# An item with the same key - throwArgumentexception

Tags: vb.net

I hope this question doesn't exist yet, because I already searched and couldn't find it... I have a function that scans the windows processes, and it worked very well, but I started to receive an error "An item with the same key", but the error is not caused all the time, Below is my function that is causing the error

```
Private Function enumWindowsInternal(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
    Try
        If hWnd <> hShellWindow Then
            Dim windowPid As UInt32
            If Not IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
            If length = 0 Then
                Return True
            End If
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, windowPid)
            If windowPid <> currentProcessID Then
                Return True
            End If
            Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder(length)
            GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1)
            dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString)
        End If
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

I have already reviewed my code, but I still haven't found the solution....

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  What do you think should happen if you get a `hWnd` that is already in the dictionary?  Is the dictionary not being cleared when expected?

Comment: I already tried to debug it, but as I said, the error is not caused all the time, when the function is called, the dictionary is also cleaned

Comment: Before adding It to dictionary, check If It exists. ```vb dictWindows.ContainsKey(hWnd)```,  and ignore It case does

Comment: this is the snippet of the function that is causing the exception:  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, windowPid)
            If windowPid <> currentProcessID Then
                Return True
            End If

Comment: There is too little information to know what the issue is - seeing the code that loops through the processes would be useful. It might also be useful to you in debugging the problem to also show the stringBuilder text - that might let you know if it is a particular process every time.

Comment: How to say, it's not a constant error, I've left it in debugging for two days and it hasn't happened again, but on other machines already running the release, it also happened once, the exception caused, it doesn't close the application, it doesn't bring me back either. no more information.... I now applied Vinicius Andrade's suggestion and will continue to follow through the logs to see if the problem persists

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary is the wrong choice. Dictionaries prevent duplicate keys, that is why we use them. When adding to a dictionary one must expect it to error and have error handling in place, which you don't (`on error resume next` - `If err.number <> 0`).

Comment: Vinicius Andrade's suggestion may be hiding an issue that you really need to be handling in another way - if an exception occurs, then it is best to find the reason why the issue occurs & then make the decision on whether the Vinicius Andrade's suggestion is the correct solution. It may very well be so, but I would prefer to understand what is really happening first because it may be a symptom of another issue in your code & hiding it may cause bigger headaches in the future.

Comment: PaulF I completely agree with you, that's why I'm resorting to the SO, I don't know how to generate this exception to be able to debug it, and since it's not constant, it's more complicated to find out. I ended up using Vinicius Andrade's suggestion so that at least this exception doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: As I said earlier - you have shown us the function where the exception occurs - not the code that calls that function, showing how you get the list of processes & loop through them - with that information, it may be possible to write a small test app to try to help you.

Comment: I'll post the entire code so you can take a look.

Comment: PaulF I ended up pasting my code as an answer and the question ended up being closed, I still have the problem, I even removed the solution that Vinicius Andrade had suggested, can you take a look at my code to see if you can find a way out of my error?